# java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity in Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I added payment gateway sdk in my flutter project but when i try to run this project natively on android then app crashes and shows the message "java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity". How to fix this?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app">
    <application
        android:label="App"
        android:icon="@mipmap/main_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value=""/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mastercard.gateway.android.sdk.Gateway3DSecureActivity"
            android:label="@string/gateway_3d_secure_authentication" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

> styles

```
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Why not run with `flutter run` command?

Comment: @MuhammadQasim Same it is crashing. But if i run natively then i get the reason of crash.

Comment: Can you share your "@style/LaunchTheme"

Comment: @Nitish Updated, check it

Answer (score 9):

Change your `LaunchTheme` from

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
```

to

```
<style name="LaunchTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: It's still crashing and same error message it is displaying.

Comment: `payment gateway sdk in my flutter project` _ can you tell me which sdk you added. It's most probably the error that some of your component required `AppCompact` as it's parent but is not able to find so.

Comment: Mastercard Payment Gateway

Comment: implementation 'com.mastercard.gateway:gateway-android:1.1.1'

Comment: Can you post your full stack track , it will help to know which exact line error is happening

Comment: After updating to latest version and also put that code which you have mentioned still it is crashing
[qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tuxedo.dafa, PID: 4715
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tuxedo.dafa/com.mastercard.gateway.android.sdk.Gateway3DSecureActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: Yes latest version won't find the crash, it was just to make you are latest androidx version , as 1.1.1 version doesn't support androidx. If I find any reason, I will let you know

Comment: But still it is crashing after installing latest version.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Same issue here, did you fixed it?

Comment: Works for flutter `3.3.2` with Naver Map. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your application tag in the manifest file

```
 <application
    android:label="my_app"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" //This line
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

Answer (score 0):

AppCompat theme is counted as legacy now, and using AndroidX you have to set Material Theme and if you don't, you'll have crashes somewhere else.
So, no matter which theme you have chosen, if your Activity Class extends AppCompatActivity, just change:

`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());`

to:

`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);`

And if your Activity Class doesn't extend AppCompatActivity  , use [`DialogFragment`](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/dialogs) instead.

And if you are using Jetpack Compose and your Activity Class extends ComponentActivity, use `AlertDialog` which belongs to Compose Library. [(Example)](https://medium.com/@dheerubhadoria/jetpack-compose-ui-alert-dialog-example-code-26240fc19811)

Answer (score 0):

If the activity triggering this error is inside a 3rd party sdk, you can ovveride the theme of the sdk's activity in your android manifiest like this:

```
  <!--        Override activity theme in SdkActivity in sdk-->
        <activity android:name="com.example.package.sdk.ui.SdkActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            />
```

Remember to update your style to reflect AppCompat:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```